# Smarty template engine is displaying css code

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

Hello i am trying to add options to a select but  smarty is outputting the css code as a string.I cant get it to work with php or javascript, I am using this function to replace the html

```
function unEscape(htmlStr) {
htmlStr = htmlStr.replace(/&lt;/g , "<");    
htmlStr = htmlStr.replace(/&gt;/g , ">");     
htmlStr = htmlStr.replace(/&quot;/g , "\"");  
htmlStr = htmlStr.replace(/&#39;/g , "\'");   
htmlStr = htmlStr.replace(/&amp;/g , "&");
<br>return htmlStr;
}
```

And it works when i replace a table element with the same variable but not as a select option.Can anybody help please?For example it will show `<b><br><small>` but not apply the css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape modificator for printing the text:

```
{$text|escape}
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."